# Exception(Crash) in iOS SKMap (Skobbler), and release memory of SKMap

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, skmaps

I am making an iOS app which uses SKMap (Skobbler).
My app got crash when the below code of SKMap execute.

```
NSArray* advices = [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] routeAdviceListWithDistanceFormat:SKDistanceFormatMetric];
```

and also SKMap consumes lots of memory of my device even after that page is removed from the navigation controller.
Is there any way to release memory of SKMap?

Comment: you need to specify crash trace, otherwise we can't help

Comment: You need to split this in 2 questions: 1 the crash report - where we need a trace. 2 the question regarding the memory consumption

Comment: @Ando,Thanks for your suggestions :-)